# Symfony2 + DataFixtures + Capifony - FATAL ERROR Doctrine Proxies - Cannot redeclare unserialize()

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

For 2 weeks i'm struggling with fallowing problem.

Im using DataFixturesBundle to load my fixtures to database. Everything works fine.
I decided to use capifony (capistrano) to deploy my application on production.

That went well too. I have implemented all things i wanted capifony to do for me with my app on production server.
But I do get one error and I dont even know what bundle is causing that.

IMPORTANT This error only shows on production server, it does NOT matter if i'm on DEV or PROD environment ( also DEBUG ), but the error never shows on my local hosts (tested on 2 computers, mac & win ).

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Proxies\TestBundleEntityPartnerProxy::unserialize() in /public_path/testapp.com/app/releases/20110929191120/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/TestBundleEntityPartnerProxy.php on line 489`

And that is right. Doctrine makes two the same methods both for unserialize() and both for serialize() in the same class (proxy).

This only happens on my production server. I can't even make the problem shows on my local host. On my local host there are no two methods with the same name (unserialize() and serialize()). There is one unserialize() and one serialize()

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers, Bart

Comment: Remember to clear cache; these proxies are 'stored entities'. Try changing Doctrine to use arraycache to see if it removes the problem; that might narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for hint.
Yes, I'm clearing cache. 
According to symfony2 reference on doctrine on [this site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) i have changes the 3 caches to array.
That didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

fixed here:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/177

Answer (score 0):

This is not capifony, but some edge case bug or situation. I'm not sure what's causing it yet. Some details here:

http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs/browse_thread/thread/435a19119e9d6bdb